# AEM design_dialog and template location

Tags: aem

Currently my design_dialog is saving the settings under etc/designs/default/jcr, how do I modify the template in order for it to save under etc/designs/(mydesign)/jcr.

I was looking at the documentation but couldn't find anything specific on how to ensure the design_dialog creates the properties under its own design template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open CRXDE.
2. Go to /yours/site/root/page/jcr:content node. `http://server:port/crx/de/index.jsp#/yours/site/root/page/jcr%3Acontent`
3. Add next property

---

```
cq:designPath : etc/designs/(mydesign)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the second paragraph of the [documentation says](http://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/designer.html). You need to add the cq:designPath to the first page of your site: